# Is is possible to float child elements inside a parent that has been absolute positioned?

Tags: html, css

I have some simple markup where I have created an overlay that takes up the whole screen (using `position: absolute`), then inside that I want to create some columns using floats.

HTML

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="position-modal">
  </div>
  <div class="modal">
    <h3>Enter email</h3>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="submit" name="" id="" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="position-modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.75);
}

.modal, .position-modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|              |             |             |
| This column  |             | This column |
| only exists  | Enter email | only exists |
| to           | +----+ ++   | to          |
| centralize   | +----+ ++   | centralize  |
| main col     |             | main col    |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
|              |             |             |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

But everything is sitting to the left,
This is what I'm getting - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwNzqa?editors=110

Is it possible to float these divs when their parent is absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `.position-modal` elements have a height of `0`. This means that the `.modal` element doesn't take them into consideration (resulting in it being positioned to the left). You will notice that if you set `min-height` on the elements, it will work as expected:

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgRoEJ)

```
.modal, .position-modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
```

However, in my opinion, the above solution is relatively hackish. Unless there is a valid reason to do that, I would simply recommend using `margin: 0 auto` to center the element horizontally instead.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrNYKN)

```
.modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33.3%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: nice one, thanks! I didn't know a column had to have some min height before other elements respected its position. thanks!

Comment: thanks I learnt more than I expected here. For example - even though it seems a bit hackish - setting `min-height: 1px;` is how the twitter bootstrap grid system works - [see github code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1618) . I had seen that property in their grid system and always wondered what it did.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.

```
<div class="overlay">

  <div class="modal">
    <h3>Enter email</h3>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text"><br />
      <input type="submit" name="" id="" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

and

```
.modal, .position-modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
   width: 33.3%;
}
```

Comment: that doesn;t position the columns - just positions the content within the columns - right?

Comment: that is correct, it centering the boxes in one div on the page